# How to remove all colors from Here Maps base layer?

Tags: here-api

How to remove all colors from Here Maps base layer? I do not want to see the freeways in pink or the streets in yellow. I want a custom grey color layer on the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [HERE Map Tile API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/topics/quick-start-map-tile.html) lets you choose different styles though you cannot completely customize the color selection (yet).

For example, here is the [reduced-day](https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/topics/example-reduced-day.html) style that removes pink freeways and yellow streets.

[image]

This is how it's done with the [JavaScript API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/overview.html):

```
//...create your own layer (with e.g. the "reduced" scheme
var reduced = platform.getMapTileService({
  type: 'base'
}).createTileLayer("maptile", "reduced.day", 256, "png8");

//Step 2: initialize a map using your custom map tile layer
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('mapp'), reduced, {
  center: {
    lat: 52.3,
    lng: 13.8
  },
  zoom: 10
});
```